# Making different styles in a latex document

Tags: fonts, formatting

In LaTeX there are such commands as `\textit{}`, `\textbf{}` to make a fragment of a text italic or bold. Can we make custom commands like this with different color, font, italic/bold/underline modifier? For example:

- `\code{}` would make text monospaced, for references like: "our program implements the class `\code{Transformer}`."
- `\term{}` for highlighting definiendums: `a term{tree} is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one path`

If there's no such possibility, what is the closest analog?

Comment: Something like `\newcommand{\code}[1]{\texttt{#1}}`? I've the impression you're after something like the `listings` package or a `glossaries`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, that's exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Logical markup is always possible with a `\newcommand{...}[1]{...}` and using grouping to prevent leaking of font declarations or color settings into the rest of code.

For more sophisticated approaches I recommend however appropiate packages for the relevant purpose. For code markup, there are `minted`, `listings` and `tcolorbox` (with its `listings` features)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\code}[1]{{\color{blue}\texttt{#1}}}

\begin{document}

\code{int main}
\end{document}
```